# simple cat echo process substitution hangs

Tags: bash, process-substitution

Simple process substitution with cat seems to hang:

```
cat >( echo hello; )
```

never finishes. Also tried:

```
cat >( echo hello; exit; )
```

Manually closing the standard out file descript from the subprocess does not work either:

```
cat >( echo hello; 1>&- )
cat >( echo hello; 1>&- exit; )
```

I have tried with GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release, GNU bash, version 4.1.2(2)-release and zsh 5.5.1 (x86_64-debian-linux-gnu)

Can someone please explain why this is happening? I Really like process substitution...

Thanks

Edit:
If cat is to read from echo, the correct redirection in process substitution is:

```
cat <( echo hello; )
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `>()` process substitution here?

Comment: May i know what are you trying to do...  cating the result of echo?

Comment: I stripped down the context as much as possible. cat was supposed to read echo. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code `cat >( echo hola; )` will never get exit because,

- it will first echo the pattern `hola`
- And takes the input to write.
- when we give `Ctrl+D` it keeps on searching the file to write.

**Option 1:** Write the context to a file which is echoed

```
cat > $( echo hola; )
```

so whatever the context we give below will be saved to file called `hola`.

Note: we can exit the cat block by `Ctrl+D`

**Option 2:** To cat the context which is echoed.

```
cat <(echo hola;)
```

Comment: Option 2 did the trick. as @muru said, 'it only had the pipe open for reading, not writing'
Thanks

Comment: No. "when we give Ctrl+D it keeps on searching the file to write" is wrong. `cat` never gets to see your ctrl-d. It waits for a ctrl-d  on the `/dev/fd/xx` that is created as output-file by the `>(echo hola)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what you're trying to accomplish, but:

1. `>(...)` makes the stdin of whatever is being run available for writing
2. `cat` expects a file that can be read

There's no guarantee that whatever is provided by (1) can be read. On macOS, I just get an error:

```
bash-4.4$ cat >( echo foo)
foo
cat: /dev/fd/63: Permission denied
```

On Linux, for me it's a pipe at the other end of which nothing is writing:

```
$ strace -e openat cat >(echo foo)
foo
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/fd/63", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

And:

```
$ ll /proc/$(pgrep cat)/fd/3
lr-x------ 1 muru muru 64 Aug 13 18:55 /proc/3381/fd/3 -> 'pipe:[37501]'
$ lsof | grep 37501
strace    3433                 muru   63w     FIFO               0,12      0t0      37501 pipe
cat       3435                 muru    3r     FIFO               0,12      0t0      37501 pipe
cat       3435                 muru   63w     FIFO               0,12      0t0      37501 pipe
```

It doesn't matter that whatever was at the other end closed stdin and exited - it only had the pipe open for *reading*, not writing, and nothing was written to the pipe. So `cat` will remain there, waiting for the read to finish. (Both `strace` and `cat`  here have an open file handle for writing to that pipe, but that's because bash opened it for writing and made it available for them. Neither are going to write to it.)

Answer (score 1):

Process substitution is quite a subject of its own. The important part to realize is that it is more like a FIFO than stdin or stdout. You can see this with echo:

```
echo >( echo hello; )
```

gives you:
    /dev/fd/63
    hello

The outer-echo gives you the argument that is actually given, which is `/dev/fd/63`. So, your

```
cat >( echo hello; )
```

is actually `cat /dev/fd/43` and the output is sent to `echo hello`. (the 43 is just an example; the number is randomish, but often 63)

You can also see the difference between:

```
echo hop > >(cat)
```

which gives `hop` and

```
echo hop  >(cat)
```

which gives `hop /dev/fd/63`.

Also, as an example:

```
 sed 's/$/klap/' | tee >(sed 's/^/hop/')
```

which gives for the input `klop`

```
klopklap
hopklopklap
```

the `klopklap` is the stdout of `tee` and the `hopklopklap` is the stdout of the `sed`  in the process substitution.

So why does `cat >(echo hello)` hang? Because, as said, cat gets an argument `/dev/fd/32` and from that "file" it never gets an EOF.

Answer (score 0):

The `cat` doesn't hang, it is waiting for your input. `cat` reads standard input and writes to standard output. You do not redirect the standard input, therefor standard input is your terminal. When you type `Ctrl+D`, you indicate End-of-File, and your `cat` will terminate.

Comment: i hope `Ctrl+D` will not work in this case, since `Crtl+D` looks for filename to write

Comment: I verified this myself, it's not that difficult to past the command into a shell.

Comment: Looks for the filename to **write**..

Comment: Cat looks for file name to **read**.

Comment: even to write it need a file.

Comment: No. `cat >(echo it)` is equivalent to `cat /dev/fd/63`.

Comment: @LjmDullaart if that is true, what is the purpose of the argument `it`?

Comment: Try `echo >(echo it)` instead of `cat` and you will see that I'm right. The `it` is merely there for the `echo` within the `()`. Read my answer for further explanation.